# select a value from a table with the help of php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a variable in my php code named $user_id. This variable takes a value after executing a short script of code. I also have a table named users in my database and this table holds user_id and email. If want to select email from my database, when the user_id from my table is equal to my variable named $user_id. Can I do this? This is my query:

```
<?php

//code ...

$user_id=$_GET['user'];    //$user_id gets a value here

//now I want to select email from table users, where user_id is equal to variable $user_id

mysql_query(" SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' ");

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried without `''`? like `..WHERE user_id=$user_id` ?

Comment: what's the problem??? your code is right

Comment: stop using `mysql_*` function they are deprecated now and use string escape to stop `sql injection`. Better use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Just vistited your site and I see you have knowledge about `SQL,     E-COMMERCE,  Web based share dealing systems (project )` and `MySQL,PHP,AJAX`. By that you mean that you know they exists, but not actual expierence right? :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The code should be:

```
$email = '';
$res = mysqli_query(" SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' ");

while ($temp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $email = $temp['email'];     
}
```

Comment: `@mysql_num_rows` is bad practise.

Comment: stop using `mysql_*` function they are deprecated now and use string escape to stop `sql injection`. Better use `mysqli` or `PDO`. Also you suppressing warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work. I'd though advise you to use [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) or [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli) instead of `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated.

If for some reasons you can not switch to either of them; you should filter/sanitize your query.

Also, if `user_id` is a numeric field, you wouldn't be needing to enclose `$user_id` in quotes.

Comment: ALthough you answer is correct, you realy think somebody asking this question has any idea what you mean with filter/sanitize a query and how he should do this? My guess he will find the mysql_real_escape() method and combined with your argument to remove the quotes, will create an SQL injection while he thinks he is secure

Comment: I agree adding an example in PDO, Mysqli or both would be better than just reiterating that they shouldnt be used. Id say this should be a comment on the question unless you are willing to outline usage with an example that illustrates how to accomplish the objective of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the basics, it just needs handling and I would add a couple of checks.

```
if(isset($_GET["user"]) && $_GET["user"] != "")  //check there is a value for the user ID
{
    if(is_int($_GET["user"]))
    {    
        $user_id=$_GET["user"]);
        $email="";
        $q=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE user_id={$user_id}") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0)
        {
            while($user=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            {
                $email=$user["email"];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "no users found";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Not a valid user ID, please enter numeric value";
    }
}
else
{
     echo "No UserID";
}
```

hjpotter92 recommends that you use mysqli or pdo for questioning your database, which I would agree with although while learning keep with mysql as there are more resources available for learning, then when confident move onto newer technologies.

Please note: I have based this on the experience I feel the user has got with PHP and MySQL not on the most modern or best practices.

Comment: You could have atleast added a check for numeric value instead of directly inserting the GET value into a query